# ROLLBACK ORACLE does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, rollback

I've a very minimalistic script that does not work.

```
SET TRANSACTION NAME 'anyname';
DELETE FROM V_RECHNUNG WHERE recno=207;
INSERT INTO V_RECHNUNG (recno) VALUES (207);
ROLLBACK;
SELECT * FROM V_RECHNUNG ORDER BY RECNO DESC;
```

I don't understand why the select statement get an entry with recno 207.
In my opinion entry with recno 207 should not exist at all.

**Important:** I checked that recno 207 did not exist before i run this script.

IS there any oracle server configuration that disables transactions?

Comment: What tool are you using to run this script?  Any chance you've configured that tool to autocommit statements it issues?

Comment: i am using a raw php script as well as php adminer to test statements.

Comment: Then the problem is almost certainly in your PHP script.  If you run this script in a vanilla SQL*Plus client, your rollback would revert both the `DELETE` and the `INSERT`.  Most likely, your PHP script is running in autocommit mode.

Comment: Are you using OCI? If you are you'll want to specify [`OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php)

Comment: use an anonymous block instead to discard auto commit

Answer (score 1):

If your table all ready had an entry for recno 207 before you had done any inserts, or any deletes, then it would make sense :)

Think About it.

You have say the following records:

Point 1:
204, 205, 206, 207, 208

Point 2:
You issued the Delete Statement for 207,  Hence, you're left with 204, 205, 206, 208

Point 3:
You issues the Insert Statement for 207, Hence, you're left with 204, 205, 206, 207, 208

Point 4: You issued a rollback, which will take you back to Point 1.. Ie: you had 207 from the start.